# Using Nuget referenced DLL in K2 Smartforms

Tags: c#, dll, k2, k2-blackpearl

i have 2 DLL (class libraries) and i want to use them in my K2 Workflow,One created using Visual studio and then the second one using Nuget From the same Visual Studio, which makes it 2, but i am having this worry.

I know you have to register the DLL but here in this case, there are 2 DLLs. (Main Program and the DLL from Nuget) Do i have to register the DLLs (including the one as gotten from Nuget ).

Comment: There are different types of DLL file.  Not all are the same.  Some can be executed by double clicking (then have a main method) and other do not.  Some are old and were developed using Windows 95 and are not compatible with c# and you need to create a wrapper method in c++ to run with c#.  So you may not need to register the DLL.  Then there are 16 bit (Win95), 32 bit, and 64 bit.  And depending on your operating system  may or may not run.  You can run method in DLL from c# using DLLIMPORT and not register the dll but the dll has to be in same folder as the c# executable.

Comment: I think i get it now. Should i want to use it, I should have the 2 dlls in one folder and have the main dll registered so it can reference the second DLL which is the nuget DLL. Do you mean this?@jdweng

Comment: Best way is to use the Project menu : Add Existing Item and browses to where dll currently is located.Using Solution Explorer right click in the Reference folder (which will contain the dll) and check option to copy to executable.This if the dll gets update the new version will get copied to executable folder.Also if you change project type from x86 to 64 bit the dll will get copied to the correct bin folder.  Also when you publish the dll will get included in the publish result. Never just put the dll into the bin folder.  If no source then put into project folder and add from project folder.

Comment: @jdweng i am talking about K2 smartforms here

Comment: You are talking about an API.  The API interface should be any different in K2 from any other API.  The API is calling a method in you application and has to adhere to the calling conventions of c#.  The API is packed in a library (dll) that is Net compatible.

Answer (score 0):

If you reference the Nuget library in your project and compile it, you should get your project .dll. This .dll can be copied onto K2 server (ServiceBroker folder) if it is a custom Broker. Its service instance can be created which will be used to generate smartobjects and can be used further in Workflows. 
If your library is a Restful service you can register it on IIS server and create REST service instance on K2.